# Fade In div content after window is resized past a certain width

Tags: jquery, resize, window, fade

I am trying to produce a function that will basically fade in some content after the page has passed a specific window width. Currently the code below will run the fade every time the window is re-sized below, at, or above 1775 pixels. I would like it to fade the content only once when the window width has hit 1775 pixels, and again if the window width has dropped below 1775 pixels.

```
$(window).on('resize', function (event) { 
    if ($(window).width() >= 1775) {   
        $('.content-genre').hide().fadeIn(250);
} else {
    $('.content-genre').hide().fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

Comment: I want the content to fade In when the window is re-sized greater than 1775 pixels, and also when the window is re-sized less than 1775 pixels.

Comment: Have you tried it with out the resize? Just keep the if and else statements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle that does what I think you are after. I used different numbers so that it was easier to see. It toggles at 800 rather than 1775.

http://jsfiddle.net/eqrQS/4/

Here is the jquery:

```
var toggle = $(window).width() < 800;
$(window).on('resize', function (event) {
    $('#text').text($(window).width());
    if ($(window).width() >= 800 && toggle) {
        $('.content-genre').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        toggle = false;
    } else if ($(window).width() < 800 && !toggle) {
        $('.content-genre').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        toggle = true;
    }
});
```

Basically, what I did was just create a variable outside of the resize scope that tracks when the event occurred. Let me know if this is not what you are after.

Comment: I've noticed that when the page is initially loaded with the width above 1175, the content will not fade on the first pass below 1775. It will only work until it is maximized above 1775 again, then will it fade. Any reason for this?

Comment: It assumes that the width starts below 1775. I have updated the jsfiddle to work whether the page starts below or above the threshold. Remember to swap all '800's for the width you want (there is a third one now in the toggle declaration).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fade in less than 1775px and greater than 1775px, don't you want it to always fade in?

You just want this to be by itself inside the jQuery call:

```
$('.content-genre').hide().fadeIn(250);
```

Otherwise, I'm confused!

Comment: I believe he wants the fade in to happen only once per time that it has passed the threshold. Once to say "you have passed 1775!" and once for "you have dropped below 1775!". What you have (and what he has) would make it constantly fade in every time the window is resized. At least, that's my interpretation. See my answer for what I mean.

Comment: OK - if that's what he wanted, I was definitely confused.